# Do you have to water winter crops?

Tags: stardew-valley

The only crops that you can grow outside of the greenhouse in winter are winter forage items (as far as I know). Specifically, if you combine the following winter forage items:

1. Crocus
2. Crystal Fruit
3. Snow Yam
4. Winter Root

You get seeds that you can plant in winter to grow these.

**Do you still need to water these seeds for them to grow in winter?** Seems kind of silly that you would have to, since the water would just freeze into ice during the winter, but oh well.

Comment: Now I [wonder](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/) about watering real plants with warm water in winter.

Comment: @user1306322: As if it would not freeze on the long term ;)

Comment: @Zaibis idk I thought salts and other stuff reduces freezing temperature below 0°C, so inside a plant it might not freeze if the winter is mild

Comment: @user1306322: I'd assume even using warm water would be cooled before the flower would have been able to consume it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, they won't grow if they're not watered.